# Question about row-reduced matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

My question is really simple. I'm reading again [Hoffman and Kunze's Linear Algebra book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0135367972) and I have the following doubt:

Let $A=(a_{ij})_{m\times n}$ be a row-reduced matrix with $r$ non-zero rows. Of course, we know that $r\le m$. My question is can we say that $r\le n$?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Rank of a matrix is equal to rank of its transpose. So, r is less than or equal to both m and n.